# Weird Issue with an image rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, image-rotation

Essentially, the code below fades images in and out. It works fine, but in testing, one of the individuals testing this on his computer left the home page up for..IDK...say 20 minutes. When he came back to his computer, the images were rotating at like less than a second intervals.

Does anything in this code appear to cause that?

```
function theRotator() {
    //Set the opacity of all images to 0
    $('div.rotator ul li').css({opacity: 0.0});

    //Get the first image and display it (gets set to full opacity)
    $('div.rotator ul li:first').css({opacity: 1.0});

    //Call the rotator function to run the slideshow, 6000 = change to next image after 6 seconds
    setInterval('rotate()',4000);
}

function rotate() {
    //Get the first image
    var current = ($('div.rotator ul li.show')? $('div.rotator ul li.show') :    $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

    if ( current.length == 0 ) current = $('div.rotator ul li:first');

    //Get next image, when it reaches the end, rotate it back to the first image
    var next = ((current.next().length) ? ((current.next().hasClass('show')) ? $('div.rotator ul li:first') :current.next()) : $('div.rotator ul li:first'));

    //Un-comment the 3 lines below to get the images in random order
    //var sibs = current.siblings();
    //var rndNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * sibs.length );
    //var next = $( sibs[ rndNum ] );

    //Set the fade in effect for the next image, the show class has higher z-index
    next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('show')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);

    //Hide the current image
    current.animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000)
        .removeClass('show');
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Load the slideshow
    theRotator();
    $('div.rotator').fadeIn(1000);
    $('div.rotator ul li').fadeIn(1000); // tweek for IE
});
```